# Error: Unsupported argument while deploying azure resource tls version

Tags: terraform, azure-rm

Helo Guys,

I have created the eventhub with terrafrom but it get deployed using TLS_verisn =1.0 now i want to change it to TLS version 1.2.
When i am trying to update this TLS change it throwing me error like " Error: Unsupported argument
minimum_tls_version = 1.2
│An argument named "minimum_tls_version" is not expected here.

Note : My [image]azurerm verison with "3.65"

Any suggestion how can i fix this error message ?

Comment: Please provide actual TF code producing the error. Also do not use properly formatted code blocks, not screenshots.

Comment: Okay Marcin thanks i will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error: Unsupported argument while deploying azure resource tls version.

`minimum_tls_version` in `Terraform` it supports latest `Azurerm` providers. check the same issue in [Github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/17030)

I updated the TLS version in Azure Event Hub using the latest Az`ureRM provider (v3.77.0)`

To resolve the issue, update your `AzureRM version` to the latest.

```json
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      name     = "example-resources"
      location = "West Europe"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_eventhub_namespace" "example" {
      name                = "demo-namespace"
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      sku                 = "Standard"
      capacity            = 2
      minimum_tls_version = 1.1
    
      tags = {
        environment = "Production"
      }
    }
```

**AzureRM Version**:

[image]

**Terraform Apply:**

Once Terraform code run, `Event Hub TLS` version has been updated.

[image]

Comment: Using latest Azurm version it works thanks